# Having trouble writing a function that adds items to different arrays in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to add items to an 
array in the local state. I could create several functions
that cater to each array in the state, but I feel like I 
should be able to only need one function that does this. The way I'm 
doing it isn't working. I probably need to take a step back and reconsider
but I was hoping to find some way to make this work.

Thanks!

```
this.state = {
  category1: [],
  category2: []
}

addItem(category, type){
  this.setState({
    category: [...this.state.category, type]
  })
}

listsOfItems.types.map((type, i) => (
  <ListItem 
    onPress={ () => this.addItem(category1, type)}
  />
))

listOfOtherItems.types.map((type, i) => {
  <ListItem
    onPress={ () => this.addItem(category2, type)}
  />
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think repetition in this case is that bad, but if you really want to generalize it, you could use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
this.state = {
  category1: [],
  category2: []
}

addItem(category, type){
  this.setState({
    [category]: [...this.state[category], type]
  })
}

listsOfItems.types.map((type, i) => (
  <ListItem 
    onPress={ () => this.addItem('category1', type)}
  />
))

listOfOtherItems.types.map((type, i) => {
  <ListItem
    onPress={ () => this.addItem('category2', type)}
  />
})
```

Comment: Beautiful! Appreciate your help :D

Comment: @Dres Awesome! No problem